# Cities problem interpretation

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Cities A, B, ... , Z are connected in a loop by 26 two way roads: A to B, B to C, .... Z to A. Each road can be destroyed with probability p independently of the others.

Find the probability that, after the rain, there are two cities that are not reachable from each other.

I do not need help solving this problem. I think I may have solved it in fact. My question is with whether or not I am interpreting it correctly as English is not my native language.

Does this mean that if one of the roads are destroyed then two cities are not reachable from each other? Does reachable from each other mean both cities must be able to travel to the other? That is, we cannot have just one way.

Thanks for help.

Comment: you'd need to destroy two roads since destroying one road puts the cities in a line and hence they're still reachable from each other.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: But they are in a loop. By having one road destroyed we prevent one city from connecting to the other. If that is the only road destroyed then yes it is possible for the other city to connect to that one but we won't have a two way connection. Doesn't reachable from each other mean both ways must work?

Comment: It is clearly given that the roads are two way. This means, that the removal of a single edge still allows every city to be two way connected to the others. However, the removal of two or more edges definitely disconnects some cities from others.

Comment: Each road is two ways. 

we have: d — a  — b  — c — d . If we destroy the road c — d, we can still reach d from c by going c -> b -> a -> d

and c from d by going d -> a -> b -> c 

the long way

Comment: Agh.. Yes. Thanks I was misunderstanding. Thanks all!!